# Importing Swift Framework into Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I need to import CVCalendar framework into my project.

This is how my Podfile looks like:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
pod 'CVCalendar', '~> 1.2.6'
end

target 'MyAppTests' do

end
```

And I am importing the framework in my swift file this way:

```
import CVCalendar
```

To use CVCalendar, you need to put two UIView objects, one for the menu and another one for the calendar itself. I can set the classes of that UIViews to the proper classes (CVCalendarMenuView and CVCalendarView, respectively) but I receive a No such module 'CVCalendar' error in the import statement.

I see that the classes inside the Pods/CVCalendar folder have an '?' beside it, as seen [here](http://imgur.com/xTIIyRI).

What do I need to do to get it working?

Thank you.

Comment: i am facing the same issue, can you share the solution you found.

Comment: I gave up using Pods and I imported classes one by one...sorry but I was unable of doing so simple thing. Maybe I am not cool enough for iOS programming.